# PHP: get array of array from an inner foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get an array of the arrays in an inner foreach loop.

My code looks something like this:

```
foreach ( $parent_terms as $parent_term ) {
    $outer_array = array();

        foreach ( $child_terms as $child_term ) {
            $inner_array = array();
            $inner = 'something';
            $inner_array[] = $inner;
            $outer_array[] = $inner_array;

            print_r($inner_array);
        }

      print_r($outer_array);
}
```

when I print outer array it starts again for each inner array.

Comment: what it suppose to be `$child_terms`? how does `$parent_terms` contains?

Comment: Because you reinitialize it all the time `$outer_array = array();`. Can you share a demo of your issue and your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update code:

```
foreach($parent_terms as $parent_term ) {
        $outer_array = array();
        foreach ( $child_terms as $child_term ) {
            $inner_array = ['something'];
            array_push($outer_array,$inner_array);
        }

      print_r($outer_array);
}
```

Comment: @flinch85 these are basic concepts in PHP. I am happy that you got your answer :)

Comment: What is the difference between OP's code and your code? Maybe I have overlooked something.